# Update two sub-arrays in one update

Tags: mongodb, atomic

Is it possible to update two sub-arrays of a documents with one update (without retrieving the document, and updating it using optimistic concurrency)?

Let's say I have the following document:

```
{ "_id" : 2,
  "arr1" : [
             { "Id" : 10, "Value" : "abc" },
             { "Id" : 20, "Value" : "abc" },
             { "Id" : 30, "Value" : "abc" }, 
             { "Id" : 40, "Value" : "abc" },
             { "Id" : 50, "Value" : "abc" }
           ],
  "arr2" : [
             { "Id" : 12, "Text" : "abc" },
             { "Id" : 22, "Text" : "abc" },
             { "Id" : 32, "Text" : "abc" }, 
             { "Id" : 42, "Text" : "abc" },
             { "Id" : 52, "Text" : "abc" }
           ]
}
```

I tried to do this, but it doesn't seem to modify the correct sub-document:

```
db.col.update(
    { "_id": 2, arr1: { $elemMatch: { Id: 30 } }, arr2: { $elemMatch: {Id: 42} } },
    { $set: {
        "arr1.$.Value": "Changed First",
        "arr2.$.Text": "Changed Second"
      }
    })
```

Comment: Seems that if this was a hash, it would better serve this update. Why is it an array of hashes instead of one hash?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean, why does your structure not look like this: http://pastie.org/6163493?

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right that would solve my problem. Can the key be an integer or does it have to be a string?

Comment: It has to be a string (IIRC).

Comment: Ok, thanks, feel free to post that as answer, I'll vote up and mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that if your data looked like this, you would be able to perform your update easily:

```
{ 
  "_id" : 2,
  "arr1" : {
    "10": "abc",
    "20": "abc",
    "30": "abc",
    "40": "abc",
    "50": "abc"

  }
}
```